# Kubernetes Minikube- Host network connection fails when i created a minikube with external switch on Windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

**Minikube setup:**
I am running `minikube` on my Windows 10 office laptop with `Hyper-v`. A Virtual switch - external mode has been created and checked `Allow management operating system to share this network adapter`.

VM works perfect and i can do deployments

**Problem:** 
The host windows 10 machine loses internet connection when Virtual switch is in external mode though i have checked the option `Allow management operating system to share this network adapter`

**Questions:**

1. How to make the host and VM share the same network?
2. Since this is my office laptop and I see `Internet Connection sharing has been disabled by network administrator`, I doubt this
   could be an issue. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Could you advise how did you install everything? Did you follow this or similar tutorial? https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c

Answer (score 1):

In the future you should provide some more details about your environment in your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

As you did not provide information, I've tried to reproduce your scenario, but could't reproduce your environment behaviour. Issue is related to your Hyper-V configuration. 
I will post some tips and common mistakes using `Minikube` on Windows.

First of all, to run `Minikube` you need to have [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/) and [docekr](https://www.docker.com/) and [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/) itself. To do it you can use [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) or follow [this tutorial](https://www.assistanz.com/installing-minikube-on-windows-10-using-hyper-v/). Tutorial since chapter `CREATING VIRTUAL SWITCH` is using `Internal switch` and mentioned `Internet Connection Sharing` is required.

As `Docker` was installed you should have already 2 Virtual Switches: `Default Switch` (The Default Network switch automatically gives virtual machines access to the computer's network using NAT) and `DockerNAT`. Next steps require to add `Virtual Switch` for Minikube as `External`. It was good explained in [this tutorial](https://octopus.com/blog/minikube-on-windows).